# How to understand this sentence about film reviews in Japanese newspapers?

Tags: translation, publishing

I'm a little bit lost here. The following sentence is about a film critic (Tsuchiya Yoshio) and the Yomiuri Shimbun. But I'm not sure about the meaning..

> 読売新聞であれば、土屋好生のような映画評論家が批評するか、あるいは記者が署名入りで一本の映画を紹介・批評しています。

Does it say something like this:

> critic (Tsuchiya Yoshio) is publishing single movie critical reviews under his name

The ...署名入りで... part is a bit tricky for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not what it says, I am afraid.  To understand this sentence, one would need to have basic knowledge of how newspaper articles are written in Japan.  I shall come back to this point later.

> 「[読売新聞]{よみうりしんぶん}であれば、[土屋好生]{つちやよしお}のような[映画評論家]{えいがひょうろんか}が[批評]{ひひょう}するか、あるいは[記者]{きしゃ}が[署名入]{しょめいい}りで[一本]{いっぽん}の[映画]{えいが}を[紹介]{しょうかい}・[批評]{ひひょう}しています。」

It says that ***two groups of people*** do film critiques in Yomiuri Newspaper.　← The main point of the sentence!

Group 1: 土屋好生のような映画評論家 "film critics such as Yoshio Tsuchiya"

Group 2: 記者 "(regular) newspaper reporters"

> 「署名入り」 means "bylined".

Unlike in some other countries, most Japanese newspaper articles are traditionally written without the names of the reporters.  According to the sentence in question, film critiques are always bylined in Yomiuri.  This is why it says 「記者が署名入りで」.

It is implying that when a professional film critic does a critique for Yomiuri (if not for other newspapers), it is naturally bylined.  Additionally, even when a regular reporter does a film critique, it is also bylined (unlike with the regular articles that s/he usually writes for Yomiuri).

「一本の」 here does not mean much.  Think of it as "a" or "one (by one)".

Comment: Thanks that makes sense now. Especially because some sentences later it is stated that, articles about terebi dorama's are usually published under a pseudonym.